# I'd like to return a single row in a query that joins two tables through a one to many relationship

Tags: oracle, one-to-many

This is an oracle system.  I have a client table (one) and an account table (many).  Frankly, I really just want to query the client table but due to poor design, there is a data element that I need for the client table that is only present on the account table - it will be the same value for all accounts for that client so I really just need to return one account row but I'm having problems accomplishing this.  Here is the query I tried:

```
Select
c.client_num,
c.client_name,
a.agency_value
from client c
inner join account a on c.client_num = a.client_num
where a.account_num in (select a2.account_num from account a2 where rownum = 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your input and doing some playing around on my own, here is the code that ultimately addressed my need:

```
select
c. client_num,
    (select a.agency_value
    from account a
    where a.client_num = c.client_num
    and rownum = 1)
from client c
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly designate how to pick one record out of many. Here's one method - use MAX

```
Select
c.client_num,
c.client_name,
(SELECT 
 MAX(a.agency_value) agency_value 
 FROM account a 
 where c.client_num = a.client_num
 -- not sure if this line is required - if not please remove
 and a.account_num in (select a2.account_num from account a2 where rownum = 1)
 ) agency_value
from client c
```

Keep in mind that by implementing this you are "cementing" your bad table design.

Are you absolutely certain that there is only ever one agency_value? use query to find any clients that have more than one agency:

```
 SELECT 
 a.client_num,
 COUNT(DISTINCT a.agency_value) CountOfAgencyValues,
 MAX(a.agency_value) max_agency_value,
 MIN(a.agency_value) max_agency_value 
 FROM account a 
 GROUP BY a.client_num
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.agency_value) > 1
```

Comment: This was helpful - I hadn't considered a sub-query like this and it makes sense.  However, it is returning a null result for the sub-query for some reason.  And do I really need the max operator since this sub-query should only return one account row (if I understand it correctly)?  I did some troubleshooting via smaller queries to try and determine the issue but no success so far.

Comment: You need an aggregate query because if this subquery was to ever return more than one row it will throw an error. Is the `select a2.account_num from account a2 where rownum = 1` actually valid logic? I preserved it in my answer but if this was just an attempt to return only one row (and it didn't work) then please remove it.

Comment: I understand your comment about cementing bad table design.  Ultimately, this is an enterprise system and I have no recourse.  To your second question about being certain that there is only ever one agency value, I have learned that there have been mistakes made and the incorrect agency value has been populated on a few records - I'm told the risk is low to the point of non-existent that the first record would contain an invalid agency value.  This query is a starting point for a data cleanup initiative so I'll take the risk.